# Return value based on date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, vlookup, range

I am running into an issue where I have various sectors that have been scored differently depending on the year. See example below:

```
                  2017       2018        2019       2020
Electrification   1.2        4.1         5.0        3.3
Energy storage    4.3        3.5         4.2        3.9
```

I want to look up the score based on the associate date. Thus, if the date is 2/24/2017 for electrification, I would like 1.2 to be returned. There might already be similar questions asked, it would be super helpful if someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect use of INDEX/MATCH/MATCH.

```
=INDEX(B2:E3,MATCH(I2,A2:A3,0),MATCH(YEAR(I3),B1:E1,0))
```

[image]

The first match returns the relative row and the second the relative column to the index range.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that your data is ranged like on the image below. If you are using Office365, you could try the formula for Electrification:

```
=XLOOKUP(YEAR(B5),$C$1:$F$1,$C2:$F2,"",0)
```

Drag it down to fill the formula for Energy storage.

[image]

If you don't have Office365, you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions like below to obtain the value of electrification. As with the previous formula, drag it down to get energy storage's result.

```
=INDEX($C2:$F2,MATCH(YEAR(B5),$C$1:$F$1,0))
```